# Running a blazor app inside of an Area inside of a MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I'm trying to add a new Area to my MVC project that will contain a new app created in Blazor .

I've added the new Area and copied all files from a template blazor project to this Area. It compiles, and I even get Intellisense on my components.

If I run my project now, my starting page is always the blazor app, while it should have been the MVC site's starting page. I only want the Blazor environment if my user surfs to "myapplication.co/blazor" (or something like that).

Steps I undertook to add a Blazor area:

1. Added a new **Area** to my existing MVC app
2. Added calls to `AddServerSideBlazor` and routing in my `Startup.cs` class

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      /* ... */
     services.AddServerSideBlazor();
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
       {
          // the controller route for the seperate area:
           endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
               name: "BlazorArea",
               areaName: "Blazor",
               pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

           //the original controller route
           endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "default",
               pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

          endpoints.MapRazorPages();
          endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
      }
   }
   ```
3. In my Blazor Area, I copied the following files from a new Blazor project

   [image: The files]

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this? If more code is needed, please let me know and I will post more code.

Thank you very much for any ideas on this!

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I did not. I resortedi n the end to create an entire new application for my blazor project, that runs from a virtual directory on the same hosting as my public website.

Comment: This may help: https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/combining-razor-blazor-pages-single-asp-net-core-3-application